# Writing a function that replaces a string using OpenText, ReadLine and WriteLine

Tags: f#

I have to write a function, given a filename, needle and a replace, that swaps the two strings in a given text document. The function has to use the System.IO.File.OpenText, WriteLine and ReadLine syntax. I'm currently stuck here, where the function seems to override given text document instead of replacing the needle.

```
 open System


let fileReplace (filename : string) (needle : string) (replace : string) : unit = 
    try // uses try-with to catch fail-cases
        let lines = seq {
                        use file = IO.File.OpenText filename // uses OpenText
                        while not file.EndOfStream // runs through the file 
                            do yield file.ReadLine().Replace(needle, replace)
                        file.Close()
                        }
        use writer = IO.File.CreateText filename // creates the file 
        for line in lines
            do writer.Write line
    with
        _ -> failwith "Something went wrong opening this file" // uses failwith exception

let filename = @"C:\Users\....\abc.txt"
let needle = "string" // given string already appearing in the text
let replace = "string" // Whatever string that needs to be replaced
fileReplace filename needle replace
```

Comment: This is not actual question, you provided some code, you described a little your problem but we still do not know what should we do. BTW this site is about solving problems but not debugging code or writing whole code for someone.

Comment: yet someone helped with the debugging;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using lazy sequence when reading `lines`. When you use `seq { .. }`, the body is not actually evaluated until it is needed. In your example, this is when iterating over lines in a `for` loop - but before the code gets there, you call `CreateText` and overwrite the file!

You can fix this by using a list, which is evaluated immediately. You also need to replace `Write` with `WriteLine`, but the rest works!

```
let fileReplace (filename : string) (needle : string) (replace : string) : unit = 
    try // uses try-with to catch fail-cases
        let lines = 
            [ use file = IO.File.OpenText filename // uses OpenText
              while not file.EndOfStream do // runs through the file 
                yield file.ReadLine().Replace(needle, replace)
            ]
        use writer = IO.File.CreateText filename // creates the file 
        for line in lines do
            writer.WriteLine line
    with
        _ -> failwith "Something went wrong opening this file" // uses failwith exception
```

I also removed the `Close` call, because `use` takes care of that for you.

EDIT: I put back the required `do` keywords - I was confused by your formatting. Most people would write them at the end of the previous line as in my updated version.

Comment: I believe you'll need `do yield` and also do in the for comprehension. :-)

Comment: @s952163 Fixed - I got confused by the OP's formatting!